# Trouble mapping to vector<std::string>

Tags: python, c++11, swig

I'm trying to extend a python wrapper for a third-party library. I'm new to swig and fairly rusty at c++ so any help is appreciated.

The swig interface file has code as follows:

```
%include "std_list.i"
%include "std_map.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_pair.i"
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"

%shared_ptr(std::vector<std::string>)

%define VECTORTEMPLATE_WRAP(vectorname, T)
%feature("ignore") vector<T>::append;
// a bunch more %feature("ignore")
%template(vector ## vectorname) vector<T>;
%enddef

VECTORTEMPLATE_WRAP(String, std::string)
```

Which I think the last part is just a more general way of saying

```
%template(vectorString) vector<std::string>
```

Then in the header file this function is declared:

```
class OBCONV OBConversion
{
int FullConvert(std::vector<std::string>& FileList, std::string&
                OutputFileName, std::vector<std::string>& OutputFileList);
}
```

However when I build the whole project and call this function in python:

```
conv = ob.OBConversion()
conv.FullConvert([],'',[])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: in method 'OBConversion_FullConvert', argument 2 of type 'std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > &'
```

Which it seems to me is skipping the %template directive completely, probably due to the "allocator" in the type parameter.

Indeed if I look in the swig-generated c++ code for this function I have

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_OBConversion_FullConvert(PyObject
     *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) { PyObject *resultobj = 0;
OpenBabel::OBConversion *arg1 = (OpenBabel::OBConversion *) 0 ;
std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > *arg2 = 0 ;
std::string *arg3 = 0 ;
std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > *arg4 = 0 ;
// ...
}
```

I'm building using c++11, which I don't think the project was originally developed for, so that may have something to do with it.

What is the allocator and how do I get swig to map the vector to a python list?

Comment: I took a look at your post. It's hard to create an mcve for the problem. I hope somebody at SO has some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: Try dividing your problem into smaller problems and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: I don't know how I can break it down any further. As far as I can tell the problem is I have vector<string,allocator<string>> instead of vector<string>. I don't know why the allocator is there and I can't seem to find reference to it anywhere in the swig documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the allocator...

`std::string` is really `std::basic_string<char>`, which is defined as the following and has default implementations of `Traits` and `Allocator`.  SWIG is just displaying those defaults.

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;
```

> ...how do I get swig to map the vector to a python list

SWIG doesn't automatically know how to convert Python lists to `stringVector`.  You get some free functionality (below) or you have to write additional typemaps to tell SWIG how to convert Python lists to vectors.

Here's a working Windows example of using string vectors.  Note using `const` correctly helps SWIG know to use input typemaps vs. output typemaps and my example has an input vector and string and an output vector:

**test.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifdef API_EXPORTS
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

API int FullConvert(const std::vector<std::string>& FileList, const std::string& OutputFileName, std::vector<std::string>& OutputFileList);
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#define API_EXPORTS
#include "test.h"

// Example to copy vin to vout
API int FullConvert(const std::vector<std::string>& FileList, const std::string& OutputFileName, std::vector<std::string>& OutputFileList)
{
    for(auto& file: FileList)
    {
        std::cout << file << std::endl;
        OutputFileList.push_back(file);
    }
    std::cout << OutputFileName << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

**test.i**

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>

%template(stringVector) std::vector<std::string>;
%include "test.h"
```

**Output**

```
>>> import test
>>> vin = test.stringVector()
>>> vout = test.stringVector()
>>> vin.push_back('abc')
>>> vin.push_back('def')
>>> test.FullConvert(vin,'test',vout)
abc
def
test
1
>>> vout[0]
'abc'
>>> vout[1]
'def'
```

Comment: This helped me solve that part of  the issue so thank you for that. I have a couple of follow-up comments and questions: -I am using Ubuntu, in case that matters. -The C++ code is third party and I am trying to avoid changing it. With that in mind, if I can't use `const` is there a work-around? I am now getting a similar error for the string argumant. Do I just use a custom typemap?

Comment: @M.Isenholt Yes, or use %apply the existing const std::string& typemap to the non-const version. You can apply it to a specific type and parameter name as well, so it won't affect other correct uses of the output type.